# Magento2: switch shipping methods placement with address fields

Tags: magento2, checkout

In the checkout page how can I switch the placement of shipping address fields below the choose shipment option?

I already extended the Checkout module and at this file
`app/code/[Vendor]/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display shippind address below shipping method.

You can find out from below file path

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

You should override **shipping.html** to your theme, changes structure which you want.

**Delete pub/static/***

> run command for deploy static content deploy
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Delete your browser cache and check your change.

Comment: should I override or extend?

Comment: Copy file from core and paste to in your theme.  now changes in your theme file.